# How to move a table from a dataset in London to EU in BigQuery on a rolling basis?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to essentially create a query that transfers the contents of the table in London `table_london` to a table `table_eu` in a dataset in the EU `dataset_eu`. I will then schedule this query on a daily basis to overwrite the created table `table_eu`.

I have looked into using the transfer option in BigQuery but this will transfer the contents of the entire dataset containing `table_london` rather than just the one table I need.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible [exporting a table between regions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#limitations_on_copying_tables) or to [copy a table to a different region](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#limitations_on_copying_tables).

There is a similar situation when [copying dataset among regions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets), even when there is in beta feature to do this, it is limited to certain regions. In addition, as far as I understand this is not an option for you since will copy all the tables.

Below, I'm listing a couple of possibilities that might help you:

- *Move query results*:

As you are querying a table, you can [save the results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#downloading_and_saving_query_results) to a local file or even to Cloud Storage, and then from the other dataset [load the data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) from that file.

- *Export a table*:

In case you want to [move the entire table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) (not a query), you would need to use the Cloud Storage as the intermediate service, and in this case you should consider the regional and multiregional locations of the bucket destination. See [exporting tables and its limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations).